# pie chart for an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I want to draw a pie chart for an array with chartkick but I have seen in the website of chartkick examples of charts to a column in a table like  `<%= pie_chart Yogurt.group(:flavor).count %>` 
. There is a way to draw just an array using chartkick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this part of their website https://chartkick.com/#data -

```
<%= pie_chart [["Football", 10], ["Basketball", 5]] %>
```

If you are using a database then do this -

Define it in the controller -

```
def index
  @piechartdata = Sport.pluck(:name, :id)
end
```

That will give you exactly this format -
[["Football", 10], ["Basketball", 5]]

Then in your view -

```
<%= pie_chart @piechartdata %>
```

Comment: The problem is my array consists of hundred elements so that I can't write every element in chartkick. I need to call the name of the array direct.

Comment: Emily, you could form the above string algorithmically from, say, the array `[["Football", 10], ["Basketball", 5]]`. The same could code could be used regardless of the size of your array.

Comment: ...For example, `arr = [["Football", 10], ["Basketball", 5]]; "<%= pie_chart [" + arr.map { |item,pct| "[\"#{item}\", #{pct}]" }.join(', ') + "] %>" #=> "<%= pie_chart [[\"Football\", 10], [\"Basketball\", 5]] %>"`.